# Ghana Passport renewal

Tags: visas, russia, passport-renewals, ukraine, ghanaian-citizens

I'm a Ghanaian student living in the Ukraine and my passport will expire in October this year, I will need to go to Russia and renew it since Ghana doesn't have embassy in Ukraine. Do I need a visa to travel to Russia to renew my passport?

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, yes you do need a visa to enter Russia https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b